# TypeError while looping through argv (Python)

Tags: python, argv

Trying to iterate through command line argument to check if each of the chars inside the string is an alphabet.

TypeError: string indices must be integers

```
import sys

k = sys.argv[1]

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print("Error.")
    return 1
else:
    for i in k:
        if k[i].isalpha() == False:
            return 1
            print("Error.")
```

Comment: You’re not looping through `argv`. You’re looping over the characters in the first item in `argv`, which maybe is what you're trying do, but it's not clear. You can check whether a string is alphabetic by doing `'abc'.isalpha()`; you don't have to check each character individually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the if statement inside the else statement to
`if i.isalpha() == False:`

This is because the for loop iterates through the values of k and sets the variable i equal to the k[i]

If you would like to have the for loop set I to the indexes instead, the for loop must read as such:

```
for i in range(len(k)):
```

Comment: This makes sense. Thank you. I did not realize Python means literally "for i IN ___", therefore already iterating through the indexes, rather than in C where you assign a for loop and must use the variable[i] solution.